# How do I open a file stream in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

To give a concrete example of what I mean:

Imagine I have an HTML page that looks like this

```
<div>
   <div id="filecontents">
       <!-- some html file contents -->
   </div>
   <input type="button" />
</div>
```

I would like to be able to click on the button, and it bring me up with a "Open or save file" dialog box.

Is this even possible?

The objective of this is, is for me to be able to open up some html, text, or a CSV using the contents of a div as a data source for the file.

Comment: This is possible, although not well supported in most browsers. See my answer.

Comment: Okay, not sure I have made this clear enough.

The objective of this is, is for me to be able to open up some html, text, or a CSV using the contents of a div as a file source.

Comment: Does it have to be a client-side solution? You could do with ASP.NET or similar; the contents have to BE a file (I think), so you could save to the web server temp and then attach to the response when the user requested it. Assuming HTML 5 solution wouldn't work cross-browser yet or doesn't do what you need.

Comment: @Nikki9696 Well, in order to solve this problem, yes. (I have accepted I'm probably going to have to send content to the server to make it send it back to me (the original content for this file is coming from a silverlight control)

Comment: I think you can do that with silverlight. http://www.silverlighttoys.com/Tutorials.aspx?tutorial=6 "The Save File Dialog gives Silverlight applications the ability to send contents to the end users' machines."

Comment: Not quite - it doesnt give the "Open" bit - the asking of a browser to do the shell invoke on the file saved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using the HTML5 FileSystem APIs. A couple tutorials here:

- [Reading local files in JavaScript](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)
- [Exploring the FileSystem APIs](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/)

Browser support is weak right now, but my guess is that it's the closest to what you want.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this gets me to being able to put contents of my current page into a "save or open as a new file on my computer" box?

I may be being stupid here (likely), but I can't see it.

Comment: This gives you access to read/write files. You can easily access the contents of the current page via JavaScript.

Answer (score 6):

doesn't `<input type="file" />` do that exact thing?

Comment: +1 Yep, it does. And this is way better than those crappy Flash alternatives you see everywhere.

Comment: It doesn't allow javascript to interact with the file contents, which I think is what the OP wants.

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand all these answers that say this is not possible without a plugin.  I would say it absolutely *is* possible with standard web technologies, but requires user interaction and server interaction.  Of course you can't go reading or writing whatever you want on a user's computer from the web, but you can ask a user for a file (open), and give a user a file (save).

**To open a file with JavaScript**, use a `<input type="file" />`.  If you want, you can use JavaScript to display the open dialog by calling the `click()` method on the file input (the DOM method, not the jQuery method).  In the `onchange` handler, submit the form, read the uploaded file, and write the contents to your page.

**To save a file with JavaScript**, send the contents of the file to the server, prepare the file, and stream it back to the client with a `content-disposition` header of `attachment; filename="file.txt"`.  This header causes the file to be downloaded and saved the user's pc rather than displayed in the browser.

Do that and you've officially written your first cloud computing app!

Comment: Your method works but the OP did't mention any server / client application. You cannot do this using solely JS and HTML <5 (client side).

Comment: sorry dude... but clearly you didn't understand the whole concept of STREAMING !!

Comment: @Daniel - this question is 4 years old. In 2011 the file api did not enjoy good browser support, and support for ie6 and ie7 was still required for most web apps.  Node.js was just a baby back then. It's a whole different game today.

Answer (score 2):

`<input type="file" />` will allow you to upload a file to the server, but you have no direct access to that file, or to the local file system, from javascript - this is a security feature.

If you want to alter the page somehow based on the contents of the file, you will have to do a round-trip: upload the file to the server, then render a new page with the changes you want, and send it back to the client.

I have seen some file-stream-like code written for javascript (i.e., a flash implementation), but they must "load" files via an ajax request and then read the data as a javascript string.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the local filesystem from javascript because of security reasons. You can, however, receive files [via drag and drop in modern browsers](http://decafbad.com/blog/2009/07/15/html5-drag-and-drop) or use an [java applet](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3303561/Creating-a-Trusted-Applet-with-Local-File-System-Access-Rights.htm) that communicates with your javascript.

**EDIT:** forgot about the new HTML5 file api linked by Michael Mior. Go with his answer, he's the man. If you need cross browser support, go with the java applet, its painful but works.

Answer (score 0):

Not with pure JavaScript. You can't open a file dialog to save part of the HTML, for example. Even if you could, there is no way to open a local file with JavaScript for security reasons (otherwise, malicious web sites could steal all your data).

But every browser allows to write plugins (most of them are written in JavaScript), so you could try this approach.

Comment: Of course you can.  `var file = document.createElement("input"); file.type="file"; document.forms[0].appendChild(file); file.onchange = function() { document.forms[0].submit(); }; file.click();`.  Return the file in the server response.  What is preventing **any** malicious website from doing this?

Comment: I think you completely missed the point of both the question and my answer.

Answer (score -5):

Use this script and put it in the button that the file browser should display.

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files;
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
        }
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
                return function(e) {
                    var span = document.createElement('span');
                    span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result, '"
                        title = "', escape(theFile.name), '" / > '].join('
                        ');
                        document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
                    };
                })(f); reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

Comment: This website is in english, please write in english.