# Open a file for reading and writing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, client-side, client-side-scripting

I would like a way of doing this:

1. User selects client-side file from prompt.
2. Browser passes file reference to client-side code.
3. Code can read and write to the file indefinitely without any more user interaction.

It needs to run in the browser.

(This is not a duplicate of [How do I open a file stream in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750594/how-do-i-open-a-file-stream-in-javascript#comment49595926_6750891); that question is over 5 years old and the file APIs have changed a lot since then. Also, it doesn't keep the file open.)

Comment: So look into the HTML5 file api

Comment: @epascarello I've tried that. It mentions reading from the file system and saving to it, but I need to know how I can get a reference to a file that I can read from and save to without further prompting.

Comment: So you want to open a file on the client and manipulate it directly from the server? i don't think thats possible from a browser.

Comment: @litelite Kind of, except all the code is client-side.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 i dont think you can open a file w/o re-prompting the user unless your code is privileged in the browser (like a browser extension). I have found an [api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/OSFile.jsm) that let you do exactly what you want. but you need privileges to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you can open a file w/o re-prompting the user unless your code is privileged in the browser (like a browser extension). I have found an [api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/OSFile.jsm) that let you do exactly what you want. but you need privileges to use it.

Comment: Do you know how to create a prompt with a file picker in it that returns the file path? I have needed to know for many reasons but have never found it out. I can work around this by creating my own, but I'm interested to know if there is a way. (I doubt it though! There's no reason for there to be.)

Comment: The file object the file picker return used to have it, but now for security reasons it's filed with garbage. MAYBE if you create an extensions you will be able to but if you are a simple webpage i don't think they will ever let you get a path.